# An integer or floating-point expression x can be converted to a boolean value

Tags: java, int, boolean, specifications

Java Specification says (§4.2.5):

«An integer or floating-point expression x can be converted to a boolean value,
following the C language convention that any nonzero value is true, by the
expression x!=0.»

May be someone knows, what convertion way they mean?

Comment: They just mean that if you've got a number that you want to use as a boolean, you have to write `x != 0` (or whatever the variable happens to be).  Java doesn't automatically treat numbers as booleans, the way C does.

Answer (score 2):

This is for people who come to Java with the knowledge of C, which allows you to write code like this:

```
int x = ...
if (x) {
    ... // Do something
}
```

Above, integer `x` is used in a context where a logical expression is expected. C implicitly converts `x` to boolean by comparing it to zero. An equivalent Java code must do the comparison explicitly:

```
int x = ...
if (x != 0) {
    ... // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure C it can be parsed compile-time as a boolean.
That is it can be used as a boolean.

```
int a = 1
int b = 0

if a:
    ...
    //This will run as it's true.
if b:
    ...
    //This won't run as it's false
```